# "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" при попытке работы с @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Есть костяк приложения, написанный на Spring Boot + Spring Security. При попытке доступа к контроллерам, защищённых с помощью `@PreAuthorize`, выбрасывается следующее исключение, которое приводит к генерации ответа HTTP 500:

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
>         at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at foo.bar.baz.controllers.AuthenticationController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e90741e.getSelf() ~[classes/:na]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
>         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]

Насколько я помню как должен работать Spring Security в этом случае, я мог бы зарегистрировать фильтр, генерирующий HTTP 401 примерно таким образом:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration
    extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

    @Override
    protected final void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity)
            throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

...

}
```

Но по какой-то причине дело даже не доходит к фильтру. Тем не менее, если в тестах аннотировать тесты `@WithMockUser`, то `@PreAuthorize` работает отлично. После долгих поисков и написания даже спайка, в котором мне, к сожалению, не получилось повторить проблему, я могу только негусто сказать, что проблема возникает только, если даже в "голой" конфигурации присутствует `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` с `prePostEnabled=true`. Отключить не могу -- `@PreAuthorize` жизненно нужен. Потратив впустую несколько недель, я ума не приложу, как оно работает в других модулях без проблем, а здесь -- нет. Встречал мнения, что не регистрируется и не срабатывает `springSecurityFilterChain`, но, снова же, раньше такого никогда не встречал и вообще затрудняюсь что-либо теперь искать по этому вопросу. Имеются следующие зависимости:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.4.3.RELEASE:pom
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.3.RELEASE
- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.1.RELEASE
- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.1.RELEASE
- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.1.RELEASE

Заранее спасибо за любые наводки или пинок в нужном направлении.

Comment: `если в тестах аннотировать тесты @WithMockUser, то @PreAuthorize работает отлично` -> а в боевом режиме если пользователь не авторизован, что происходит?

Comment: @MrFylypenko Не наводка, но вполне качественный пинок: должен признаться, слишком "увлёкшись" поиском проблемы, не запускал в "боевом" режиме ни разу. Вообще. За всё это время. Если в обычном режиме, тогда всё нормально и '@PreAuthorize' работает так как нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жаль, что тонны кода, приведённого в вопросе, не раскрывают суть проблемы, как оказывается. После нескольких экспериментов, по наводке [MrFylypenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218319/mrfylypenko), я запустил сервер в "производстенном" режиме, и, как оказалось, оно работает. Сужая область "исследований" к тестам, мне пришлось проверить, всё ли правильно проаннотированно, включая `@WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener`, подобно тому, как работают другие модули, на которые я ссылался в вопросе. И тогда меня посетила мысль, что минимальная область действия тестовых слушателей -- это сам тест, и скорее всего `MockMvc`, который я не включил в вопрос, не настроен надлежащим образом. И как оказалось, так и есть, потому что в одном из базовых классов он инициализировался так:

```java
mvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
    .build();
```

Это и была причина, потому что экземпляры `MockMvc` также должны быть корректно настроены:

```java
mvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
    .apply(springSecurity()) // не работало из-за отсутствия этой строки
    .build();
```

Хороший пример не доверять правилу "аннотации сами всё сделают за тебя". К сожалению, было потрачена уйма времени из-за чудовищной невнимательности, но я рад, что наконец-то нашёл причину.